# why dont I see the objects in my scene, when using python

Tags: python, objects

I'm trying to list all objects in my blender file, using something like:

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects: 
    print(obj.name, obj.type)
```

For some reason this gives me:
Camera CAMERA
Cube MESH
Light LIGHT

But my own blend file does not have an object called Cube, and has lots of other objects with many other names.

I'm running the script like:

```
 /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender -b -P print_smooth_terminal.py bubbles5.blend
```

I've tried listing out the scenes:

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    print(scene, scene.name)
```

... but this only shows one scene.

Spent hours trying to figure this out. No joy :/

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that the order of the command-line arguments to Blender matters.

Putting `bubbles5.blend` after `-P print_smooth_terminal.py` meant that `-P print_smooth_terminal.py` was executed on the default Blender scene, not the scene I wanted it to operate on.

By simply putting `-P print_smooth_terminal.py` before `bubbles5.blend`, everything works ok...